# Dividing $n$ gon into 4 equal parts

Tags: geometry

Find sufficient and necessary conditions on the sides and angles of a convex $n$-gon $A_1A_2 \cdots A_n$ ,so that there is an inner point $M$ such that two perpendicular lines through $M$ divide the $n-$gon $A_1A_2 \cdots A_n$ into four equal polygons of equal area . Determine point $M$ .

Comment: Do you mean the four component polygons to be congruent?

Comment: What's the source of this problem, please?

Comment: WHAT'S THE SOURCE OF THIS PROBLEM, PLEASE?

Comment: @GerryMyerson , it was from some textbook I saw in a library , whose name I have forgotten

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601228/algorithm-of-cutting-a-polygon-into-equal-parts ?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Not quite. Note the requirement for perpendicularity of these cuts. In the comment of the solution, they bring of the question of whether this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is equal area, then such a dissection always exists.

Claim: given any angle $\theta$, there always exists a unique line $l_\theta$ with that slope such that the area of the figure is equally split.

Claim: as $l_\theta$ varies continuously wrt theta.

Now, consider $l_\theta, l_{\theta+90^\circ}$. It divides the figure into 4 parts where the opposite areas are the same.

Apply a continuity argument + intermediate value theorem to show that there is an angle where all 4 parts have equal area.