# Radial Division of a Figure into Equal Parts

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Given an $n$-gon, $P$, for which numbers $k$ must there exist a point $x$ so that there are $k$ equally spaced rays emanating from $x$ which divide $P$ into $k$ equal area parts?

For $k=2$ we can find a point $x$ by sweeping a line at fixed angle across the figure.

For $k=4$ the problem was asked here:
[Dividing $n$ gon into 4 equal parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838257/dividing-n-gon-into-4-equal-parts?rq=1)
. The idea of the solution being find a line dividing the figure in half,  sweep in another line, perpendicular to the first until it divides the figure in half another way.  Then continuously shift about the intersection point and apply the intermediate value theorem to get two consecutive quadrants equal from which you can deduce all $4$ quadrants are equal.

For $k=3$ a similar argument works I think. For $k \ge 5$ I don't know.