# Divide set of points by a plane so sum of distances of points on either side of plane is equal

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a finite set of points A and another point C. I would like to *compute* a vector N so that the plane defined by C (point on plane) and N (normal of plane) divides all points in A with the sum of distances of points to the plane on either side of plane is equal.

What is this problem called? What are good algorithm to solve it?

Comment: By *compute* you mean "not algorithmically?"

Comment: No, actually I man algorithmically.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a look at [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890992/splitting-polygon-in-4-equal-parts/891121#891121).

The existence of such a plane is granted by the Borsuk-Ulam theorem,
since the map $\varphi:S^2\to\mathbb{R}$ associating *the direction of the normal vector* with *the difference of the "total distances" in the two half-spaces cut by the plane through $C$ orthogonal to $N$* is a continuous function (almost everywhere $C^{\infty}$) and it is antipodal on $S^2$.

Hence you can find $N$ through any algorithm for finding the zeroes of an almost-everywhere-$C^{\infty}$ function over a compact 2d-set.